# Gentoo based custom Live CD won't boot

Tags: linux, boot, livecd, gentoo, squashfs

I followed [this guide](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HCZkbCfsYdIJ:en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Build_Your_Own_LiveCD_or_LiveDVD%20&cd=1&hl=iw&ct=clnk&gl=il) for building a Gentoo based custom live CD but I didn't manage to preform a complete boot.
The kernel boots from the initrd and start scanning modules. After that it states "Could not find the root block device in ." and offers me to drop to shell. When I try to enter shell mode and execute `cat /dev/loop0` I get nothing. It seems that the kernel doesn't bind the squashfs image to the loop device.
My menu.lst:

```
default 0
timeout 7
splashimage=/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz

title=LiveCD
        kernel /boot/kernel-genkernel-x86_64-3.7.10-gentoo-r1 real_root=/dev/loop0 looptype=squashfs loop=/livecd.squashfs vga=ask initrd udev nodevfs cdroot dodmraid  rootfstype=squashfs
        initrd /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-3.7.10-gentoo-r1

title=LiveCD NO-FB
        kernel /boot/kernel-genkernel-x86_64-3.7.10-gentoo-r1 real_root=/dev/loop0 looptype=squashfs loop=/livecd.squashfs initrd udev nodevfs cdroot dodmraid rootfstype=squashfs
        initrd /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-3.7.10-gentoo-r1

title=Memtest86+
        kernel /boot/memtest86plus/memtest.bin
```

fstab:

```
/dev/loop0              /               squashfs        defaults             0 0
none                    /proc           proc            defaults             0 0
none                    /dev/shm        tmpfs           defaults             0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `make allmodconfig` made configuration with the following variables turned on:

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL
CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE
```

Which caused the kernel to override the command line parameter given in grub configuration with an empty command line, resulting a failure in the init script.